# Selenium - Could not initialize class com.opera.core.systems.runner.launcher.OperaLauncherRunner

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to set up Selenium server. It already works with Firefox and Chrome, but I can't get it to work with Opera.

I am using php-webdriver ( https://github.com/Element-34/php-webdriver ). When I try to create session, it throws PHPWebDriver_UnhandledWebDriverError Exception with message 'Could not initialize class com.opera.core.systems.runner.launcher.OperaLauncherRunner'

```
$OperaDriver = new PHPWebDriver_WebDriver('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub');
$Session = $OperaDriver->session('opera'); //throws exception
```

I run everyting locally (Windows 8.1) and everything is up to date.

There's not much documentation for this, so I didn't find anything what can cause this problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: same problem here (Win 8.1. opera 28), did you found a solution?

Comment: nope, I gave up. Using just firefox and chrome driver, that run fine

Comment: okay, never mind since I found out, that even the professionals from saucelabs support just opera 9,10 on Windows 8 https://saucelabs.com/platforms/